# Rectangulo SVG dentro de outro rectangulo

Tags: html, svg

Quero colocar um elemento rect dentro de outro elemento rect. Utilizei o opacity, mas mostra-me sempre um rectangulo. Utilizei o seguinto codigo:

```
<svg width="400" height="180">
 <g>

  <rect x="50" y="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:black;stroke:black;stroke-width:2;fill-opacity:0;stroke-opacity:1;">

  <rect x=50 y=30 width=50 height=50>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Fecha as tags `<rect` devidamente com `/>` assim funciona para mim. http://jsfiddle.net/L4m2ppe0/

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de fechar as tags `<rect` devidamente com `/>` senão o HTML vai pensar que o segundo `rect` é descendente do primeiro.

Podes usar `<rect ... />`:

```html
<svg width="400" height="180">
    <g>
        <rect x="50" y="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:black;stroke:black;stroke-width:2;fill-opacity:0;stroke-opacity:1;" />
        <rect x=50 y=30 width=50 height=50 />
    </g>
</svg>
```

ou podes usar `<rect ...></rect>`:

```html
<svg width="400" height="180">
    <g>
        <rect x="50" y="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:black;stroke:black;stroke-width:2;fill-opacity:0;stroke-opacity:1;"></rect>
        <rect x=50 y=30 width=50 height=50></rect>
    </g>
</svg>
```